Proving $N(\textrm{Cy}(G))=\textrm{Cy}(\textrm{Hol}(G))$
Let $G$ be a finite group, $\textrm{Hol}(G)$ a holomorph of $G$, and $\textrm{Cy}:\textrm{Hol}(G) \to S(G)$ a Cayley embedding. What I want to know is that the normalizer $N(\textrm{Cy}(G))$ in $S(G)$ is equal to $\textrm{Cy}(\textrm{Hol}(G))$. In particular, the following proof is complete if it can be shown that $f(x)=(\sigma(e))^{-1}\sigma(x)$ is a homomorphism when $\sigma \in N(\textrm{Cy}(G))$. Here are some definitions and what I proved.
Definitions
$S(G):$symmetric group of $G$
$\textrm{Hol}(G) = G \rtimes \textrm{Aut}(G)$
$\textrm{Cy} : \textrm{Hol}(G) \to S(G) \quad \textrm{Cy}(g,f)(x)=gf(x)$
What I proved
$(1) N(\textrm{Cy}(G)) \supset \textrm{Cy}(\textrm{Hol}(G))$
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Cy}(g,f)^{-1}\textrm{Cy}(g',\textrm{id})\textrm{Cy}(g,f)&=\textrm{Cy}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}),f^{-1})\textrm{Cy}(g',\textrm{id})\textrm{Cy}(g,f)\\
&=\textrm{Cy}(f^{-1}(g^{-1}g'g),\textrm{id})\\
&\in \textrm{Cy}(G)
\end{align*}
$(2) N(\textrm{Cy}(G)) \subset \textrm{Cy}(\textrm{Hol}(G))$ with one assumption
Suppose $\sigma \in N(\textrm{Cy}(G)), g=\sigma(e), f(x)=g^{-1}\sigma(x)$.
If it can be proven that $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f$ will be injective as follows.
$$
f(x)=g^{-1}\sigma(x)=e \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; \sigma(x)=g \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; x=e
$$
Since $G$ is a finite group,$f$ is an isomorphism, and it can be proven that $\sigma=(g,f)$.

There is no need to assume that $G$ is finite, this result is true for all groups $G$.
Since ${\rm Cy}(G)$ is transitive, we can assume in the proof of (2) that $\sigma(e)=e$, and so we just need to prove that $\sigma$ is a homomorphism (in which case it is an isomorphism since it is bijective).
Let $x \in G$. By definition of the map ${\rm Cy}$, we have ${\rm Cy}(x)(e) = x$ so, by the rule for conjugation of permutations, we have $\sigma{\rm Cy}(x)\sigma^{-1}(e) = \sigma(x)$ and, since $\sigma \in N({\rm Cy}(G))$, this imples that $\sigma{\rm Cy}(x)\sigma^{-1} = {\rm Cy}(\sigma(x))$.
Then, for $x,y \in G$,
$${\rm Cy}(\sigma(xy))=\sigma{\rm Cy}(xy)\sigma^{-1}=\sigma{\rm Cy}(x)\sigma^{-1}\sigma{\rm Cy}(y)\sigma^{-1}={\rm Cy}(\sigma(x)){\rm Cy}(\sigma(y))={\rm Cy}(\sigma(x)\sigma(y)),$$
and so, since the map ${\rm Cy}$ is bijective, we have $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$, as required.
